# Find unchanged areas on multiple images

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, mask

I'm trying to detect the areas that don't change between 40-50 images (basically the unchanged pixels). For simplicity I'll provide an example with only 3 images:

- [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O4RO.png)
- [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Brdd9.png)
- [Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1EzI.png)

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gJDO.png) could be the output of the program, a mask showing what was untouched in those 3 images.

I've tried with [compare](https://imagemagick.org/script/compare.php) from ImageMagick:

```
compare *.png -fuzz 20 -compose src mask.png
```

but doesnt seem to support an array of files, as it only produces the differences between the first two images: [mask.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfOxO.png)

Iterating trough all the images and joining the masks is discarded because it would generate lots of unwanted files (and probably be slow)

I'm aware that this is the same question as "how to get differences between images", but all the solutions given on those questions doesn't apply when there is more that 2 images

Is there any simple way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by computing the standard deviation across all the images and then taking the darkest region. (Low standard deviation means similar). Threshold at some level and negate so that those regions are white. This can be done using one of my bash unix shell [scripts](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick) for imagemagick, called stdimage, which does the std across all the input images. Then threshold and negate.

Images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
stdimage image1.png image2.png image3.png miff:- | convert - -threshold 0 -negate result.png
```

[image]

Without my script, one could compute the std across all images by using -fx.

If you have one image that is just the background, then you could subtract that from every image and threshold. Then multiply all the thresholded image together using -evaluate-sequence multiply. That would get the same result after negating.

Answer (score 2):

If you use **ImageMagick** `-evaluate-sequence` operator to find the maximum  (i.e. brightest) pixel at each point amongst your images and again to find the minimum (i.e. darkest) pixel at each point... you could then calculate the difference between the two results and if there is no difference that pixel is pretty likely constant throughout your set of images:

```
magick *.png -evaluate-sequence max    \
    \( *.png -evaluate-sequence min \) \
    -compose difference -composite -threshold 0 result.png
```

Or, if you have plenty of RAM, you can avoid reading them twice by making a copy of your sequence in an MPR:

```
magick *.png -alpha off -write MPR:seq     \
               -evaluate-sequence max      \
    \( MPR:seq -evaluate-sequence min \)   \
    -compose difference -composite -threshold 0 result.png
```

---

On reflection, this is actually rather similar to Fred's answer, because it stands to reason that the variance will be zero if the maximum and minimum are the same - though statistics is not my strong point... so if anybody knows better, please ping me!

Comment: @Nimantha I would prefer the comment to remain as I am unsure if this is the best/simplest method and I would like to learn too if someone knows a better way. Also, it's only fair to warn users if I am not certain about my answer.

Comment: Noted. "though statistics is not my strong point" could be viewed as commentary (not required on the answer). While the last section is implied ("so if anybody knows better, please ping me!") - users can use comments to provide feedback or create a new answer.

Comment: “pretty likely constant” -> “must be constant”. Yes, equal min and max implies zero variance. But small variance doesn’t mean that one image cannot be different at that pixel. This solution is more robust than the variance one.